# divide the html page to fill up all the window with a top panel with the minimal height necessary, a left panel and a right panel with a fixed width

Tags: html, css

How to divide the html page to fill up all the window with a top panel with the minimal height necessary, a left panel and a right panel with a fixed width?

I tried as follows, but the right panel takes more than 100px. It works if I remove the top header. Also, using `height: 100%` is not correct, as the top header takes some space also.

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
<tr><td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">top</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td style="height: 100%">left</td>
  <td style="width: 100px; height: 100%">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with this layout?  I presume that you want the `top` row to fill 100% of the width of the table, rather than the screen?  Setting `width: 100%` is causing it to fill the availble width currently.

Comment: It's **very** old-school to use tables for layout. There are MUCH better option - https://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are determined to use a table to perform your layout, the following may help with your specific issue.

At the moment, you are specifying that the top row should take 100% of the available width.  In this case, it will take the available page width, not the width of the table.

To rectify, simply remove the `width: 100%` on the top row and allow the row below to define the width of the table based on the settings on the `left` and `right` columns:

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
<tr><td colspan="2">top</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td style="height: 100%">left</td>
  <td style="width: 100px; height: 100%">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However, now the `left` column will automatically take the available width, which will also cause your `top` row to expand automatically.  The `right` column will now be the fixed `100px` you requested.

**A note on laying out content**

Modern HTML5 and CSS3 bring a plethora of powerful layout methods for content.  I strongly encourage you to investigate these for laying out a web-page as opposed to relying on tables.

Although tables are sometimes necessary (I'm thinking laying out emails for older-Outlook versions), most of the time you can rely on modern techniques to achieve the same.

A Google of `HTML5 CSS3 layouts` will provide a plethora of useful content, but a starting point could be [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) which have a good basic introduction.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. But I still do not understand why. You say "it will take the available page width, not the width of the table.". The width of the page and the width of the table should be the same, as I set `<table style="width: 100vw;">`.